# Showing $\limsup_{h \to {0}}\frac{O(h^2)}{h^2}<\infty$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Let

> $$y(h)=1-2\sin^{2}(2\pi h) ,  f(y)=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt(1-y^2)} $$

Justify the statement

> $$f(y(h))=2-4\sqrt{2}\pi+O(h^2)$$

where

> $$\limsup_{h \to {0}}\frac{O(h^2)}{h^2}<\infty$$

Comment: Your title (and the answer you accepted) are dealing with the definition of $O(\cdot)$.  The question you posted is to "justify the statement" in the second displayed equation, for which you would need to use the definitions in the first and last displayed equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition

> $$g(x)=\mathcal{O}(f(x))\iff\exists M>0,\; |g(x)|\le M|f(x)|.$$

Hence

$$\limsup {\mathcal{O}(f(x))\over f(x)}\le \limsup \left|{\mathcal{O}(f(x))\over f(x)}\right|\le M$$

taking $f(h)=h^2$ gives the result.